# Install R-Package from Github

Tags: r, github

I am trying to install a package from Github, but it's showing me always the same error:

```
> install_github("jfpalomeque/Momocs")
Installing github repo Momocs/master from jfpalomeque
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/jfpalomeque/Momocs/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\DOCUME~1\Ged\CONFIG~1\Temp\RtmpE15W58/master.zip
Installing Momocs
"C:/ARCHIV~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/i386/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL "C:\Documents and  \
  Settings\Ged\Configuración  \
  local\Temp\RtmpE15W58\devtools5a86536733\Momocs-master"  \
  --library="C:/Archivos de programa/R/R-3.1.0/library" --install-tests 

Warning: invalid package 'C:\Documents and Settings\Ged\Configuración          local\Temp\RtmpE15W58\devtools5a86536733\Momocs-master'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Error: Command failed (1)
```

My sesion:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

Comment: Have you loaded `devtools` library?

Comment: Good news for you (kind of) - installs fine for me on linux.

Comment: you might be having trouble because of the spaces in your file paths?

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure you have the newest version of the devtools package. This is 1.5 at the moment.To do so run

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

Then you have 3 options:

1:) You can try using different parameter alternatives in the devtools package.

```
install_github("Momocs",username="jfpalomeque")
```

2:) Another way is trying to download the zip file and install it with the normal install.packages() function in R with:

```
install.packages(file_name_and_path, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

3:) You can also just install it from cran with

```
install.packages("Momocs")
```

as it is the same version and the same author as the github package.

Regards

Comment: Try removing the spaces from the file path in your system please

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I am having the same problem using diferent parameters, and the CRAN version is not the same than Github.

Comment: And the path is automatic, I only type '>install_github("jfpalomeque/Momocs")'

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with the spaces. Please try downloading the package from GitHub manually to a folder with no spaces in the path. And then use option number 2

Comment: In Linux, `install.packages()` will not work with the source code in a downloaded .zip (the usual option to download code from github). You can (1) use `devtools::install_local()`, or (2) uncompress it first and use `install.packages()` (but pointing to the uncompressed folder), or (3) download the .tar.gz compressed file accesible in <https://github.com/account/reponame/archive/branchname.tar.gz> and then use `install.packages()`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try 
`devtools::install_github("vbonhomme/Momocs")` instead. As stated before, you need `devtools` to make it work.

Also, Momocs 1.0.0 is on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Momocs/index.html) so you can simply: `install.packages("Momocs")`.

Have a look to the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Momocs/vignettes/Momocs_speed_dating.html) for a nice entry point into the package. And I'm here to help if required.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest R packages from github repository.

Steps to install R packages if you don't have internet access on your server/machine.

1. First you need to install R packages devtools and git2r (git2r not
   mandatory, it depends on the package you would like to install )
2. Download the master zip file from git package location
3. Unzip the package on a windows path
4. Create a source: source <- devtools:::source_pkg("windows
   path/master directory name")
5. install(source)

Hope it helps.