# Unable to install [R] package slidify on Windows

Tags: r, install.packages, slidify

I downloaded *ramnathv-slidify-4260813.zip* and copied it into *C:/Users//Documents/R/win-library/3.5*

On *Windows 7 64bit* machine

In *Rstudio* with Admin privileges I ran this:

> install.packages("~/R/win-library/3.5/ramnathv-slidify-4260813.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users//Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open compressed file 'ramnathv-slidify-4260813/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>   Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

How can I bypass the Error message above and install 'slidify' successfully on my machine?

thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't installing from GitHub?

Comment: Tried this and the same result:> install.packages("C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ramnathv-slidify-4260813.zip", 
+                  destdir = '~/R/win-library/3.5/',
+                  lib = '~/R/win-library/', 
+                  repos = NULL)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'ramnathv-slidify-4260813/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Comment: NColl: I do not know how to run commands on GitHub.com I did find one of tutorials like this one: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/githubinstall/vignettes/githubinstall.html  I just cnanot figure out where to run these commands so i have been trying via RSTudio   thanks

Comment: Ok, you can install packages to `r` from github using the `devtools` package`devtools::install_github('ramnathv/slidify')`
`devtools::install_github('ramnathv/slidifyLibraries')` The answer to this question covers installing from GitHub https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914510/install-r-package-from-github

Comment: Managed to install by first downloading 'slidify' and 'slidifyLibraries' gz files and then running: _install.packages("C:/Users/.../Downloads/ramnathv-slidify-v0.3.3-154-g1dd41a3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
install.packages("C:/Users/.../Downloads/slidifyLibraries-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")_ commands in RStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to install by first downloading 'slidify' and 'slidifyLibraries' gz files and then running: *install.packages("C:/Users/<...>/Downloads/ramnathv-slidify-v0.3.3-154-g1dd41a3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

*install.packages("C:/Users/<...>/Downloads/slidifyLibraries-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")* commands in RStudio

Alternatively, in *RStudio* this can be done via GUI: click *Packages* > *Install Packages* > in *Install Packages* window select *Install from: package archive ...* > then *Browse* to the location you downloaded your file to > click *Install*.

Thanks