# Loading arcgisbinding package in R?

Tags: r

Is anyone unable to load the arcgisbinding package in R?

When I try to install it from the menu it says its not available. So when I manually download it from the Github page and select the package, it allows me to open it. However, when I try to load it into my library it throws the error, " package ‘arcgisbinding’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it" which is of course untrue, as I am working in R 4.0.0.

Is there something wrong with the package?

Comment: When you say "Install it from the menu" are you referring to RStudio?  A quick look on the cran site suggests that the package is not on cran, but only on github. Have you looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/githubinstall/vignettes/githubinstall.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914510/install-r-package-from-github for ideas on how to download packages from github

Comment: They have not made this package compatible with R 4.0.0, so I just uninstalled that and then re-downloaded 3.6.0.